# How can I add an oninput attribute to an element through HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am currently constructing a sidebar in HTML using JavaScript. Right now I am trying to append a search field to the sidebar.

```
var searchField = document.createElement("input");
    searchField.placeholder = "Search";
    searchField.type = "text";
    searchField.id = "search-field";
    searchField.className = "txtclring";
    searchField.oninput = "search();";
    searchContainer.appendChild(searchField);
```

My problem is with the oninput attribute. All the other attributes show up in the document fine, but the oninput does not show up as an attribute. The code that this constructs looks like this in Chrome DevTools:

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" id="search-field" class="txtclring">
```

How can I get the oninput attribute to show up and work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're making an Element.  Stop thinking in terms of inline event bindings and think of proper event bindings.  Use `addEventListener`

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of intrinsic event properties (like `oninput` and `onclick`) need to be **functions**, not strings.

```
searchField.oninput = search;
```

---

If you want to pass a string, you need to set the attribute instead.

```
searchField.setAttribute("oninput", "search();");
```

… but don't. This is `eval` in disguise, and plays horrible games with scope while making debugging hard.

---

Intrinsic event properties are bad enough. It would be better to use a modern approach. `addEventListener` was introduced in the 90s and achieved widespread browser support when IE9 came out.

```
searchField.addEventListener("input", search);
```